# Asynchronus operation inside NSOperation

Tags: ios, multithreading, networking, nsoperation, wsdl2objc

I have a web service, which I'm using to upload images to a server. I consume the service inside an `NSOperation`. When I call the methods of service synchronously, everything is ok, but when I call the methods asynchronously, the web server never receives the request. The only reason I can think of this happening is that thread was killed even though inside the web service asynchronous call there is loop which keeps the current runloop active until a response is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for `NSOperation`, you will see how to implement concurrent `NSOperations`. In short, instead of implementing `main`, you implement `start`, `isConcurrent`, `isExecuting`, and `isFinished`. So typically you would return `YES` for `isConcurrent`, start your request in the `start` method and set `isExecuting` to YES, and when your request finishes set `isFinished` to YES. For much more details please see the official Apple NSOperation class documents.